# Google analytics in android and campaigns sources in play store

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've got a question regarding google analytics in Android and campaigns.

I've read all tutorials regarding implementing GA in Android application and I think that I managed to do this correctly, since "something" is showing in GA panels (i.e. that application was downloaded, how many times etc.). But I've got problem with gathering campaigns info (or with checking if this was implemented properly).

After implemented what is written [**HERE**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) and tested in a way that was described [**HERE**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns) everything were looking good. However, when I put application to play store (but as an alpha version) and I tried to used link generated with helper tool for url with campaigns nothing happens (in GA it shows that application was downloaded but with "none" campaign).

**So my question will be:** *Is this happening because this is an alpha and url is not handling this well or because I've done something wrong, since GA and campaigns should work with alpha version too.*

At the end I only want to add, that in my case I want only tracking sources from which my app were downloaded.